# Clipping InkPresenter to drawing area

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to capture a signature in windows phone 7.1.

I can draw on the screen yet I can not limit the drawing area to the InkPresenter control except by adding some handling in the mousemove event.

How can I limit the drawing area using XAML or is this not possible?

**XAML Code**

```
<InkPresenter  Name="inkTest" Background="White"  MinHeight="180" MinWidth="250" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
private Stroke _currentStroke;

private void inkTest_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _currentStroke = null;
}

private void inkTest_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_currentStroke == null) return;
        //HACK: want to set this in XAML
        var position = e.GetPosition(inkTest);
        if (position.X <= inkTest.ActualWidth &&
            position.Y <= inkTest.ActualHeight)

            _currentStroke.StylusPoints.Add(GetStylusPoint(position));
}

private void inkTest_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    inkTest.CaptureMouse();
    _currentStroke = new Stroke();
    _currentStroke.StylusPoints.Add(GetStylusPoint(e.GetPosition(inkTest)));
    _currentStroke.DrawingAttributes.Color = Colors.Blue;
    inkTest.Strokes.Add(_currentStroke);
}

private StylusPoint GetStylusPoint(Point position)
{
    return new StylusPoint(position.X, position.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but try clipping:

```
<InkPresenter  Name="inkTest" Background="White"  MinHeight="180" MinWidth="250">
    <InkPresenter.Clip>
         <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,180,250"/>  
    </InkPresenter.Clip>
</InkPresenter>
```

Change the boundaries of the `RectangleGeometry` to what you want (or change the `RectangleGeometry` element itself if you need a different shape).